# Generalise visual studio code formatting among team to avoid merge conflicts due to auto formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

How do we make sure every member of the team have the same formatting configuration for visual studio.

Comment: don't use formatting, then those lines will not change

Answer (score 2):

So first of all, the answer to this question can very depending on the language you are formatting, but concept you will want to implement is the same across most contemporary languages, and that concept is called **Opinionated Formatting**

### OPINIONATED FORMATTING

---

I don't know what language you are writing, but you want an opinionated formatter that you will require everyone on the team to use. Opinionated formatters get the name **OPINIONATED**, because they are, opinionated. An oppinionated formatter does not have a lot of different configurations that can be altered and changed, if they have any at all.

The most popular Opinionated formatter that is used in the JavaScript & TypeScript worlds is **PRETTIER**. Truth be told, I never even heard of an opinionated formatter until I began to use prettier. When I first started using Prettier like 5 years ago, it was mostly a JS/HTML/CSS & JSON thing, but now it is used for several languages: HTML, CSS, JS, Java, JSON, JSONC, JSON5, JSX, Pug/Jade, Handlebars, MD, MDX, LESS, SCSS, GraphQL, Yaml, Vue, React, Python & more...

That is a lot of support for a single formatter, and each of those languages, have their own compiler that Prettier uses. You can also use a compiler like babel via plugins. It is important to note though, Just because prettier has language support for non web-specific languages, like Python & Java, their may be other options that are better out their.

If you are writing Python, you might want to tryout **Black**, which is said to have been inspired by Prettier's Opinionatedness [according to this article I read](https://deepsource.io/blog/python-code-formatters/). Black claims that Blackened code looks the same regardless of the machine it is formatted on.

And from what I hear, go has an opinionated formatter embedded write into the language, so you never need to worry about the way your team formats, honestly GO is doing some next level stuff.

Obviously I cannot name an Opinionated formatter for every language, and you should have included that information in your question, if you edit it in, message me please so I can update my answer later. But If your not writing JS Python, or Go, then you can probably just DuckDuckGo an opinionated formatter for your language and see what is available. If your using a popular enough language, someone will be building a formatter for it. Anyways, good luck.

---

###### On a last note, I want to quote prettier, because I remembered reading this a while back, and I think it says it all:

> ---
>
> ###### *"By far the biggest reason for adopting Prettier is to stop all the on-going debates over styles. It is generally accepted that having a common style guide is valuable for a project and team but getting there is a very painful and unrewarding process. People get very emotional around particular ways of writing code and nobody likes spending time writing and receiving nits."*
>
> ---

---